# Print maximum count of duplicate number in array

Tags: c

WAP to find the number of duplicate elements in the list. Return the number and it's frequency. If none of the numbers repeat return -1.

Input Format

- Single line input containing integers

Output Format

- Single line output containing two integers

Sample Input

```
6 1 2 3 4 5 1 7 1 8 1 9
```

Sample Output

```
1 4
```

Explanation
(1 comes 4 times)

**Here is My code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int count;
  int arr[] = {6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 7, 1, 8, 1, 9};

  int max = -1, pos;
  int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    count = 0;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
      if (arr[i] == arr[j]) count++;
    }
    if (count > max) {
      max = count;
      pos = i;
    }
  }
  if (max == 0) return -1;

  printf("%d %d", arr[pos], max + 1);

  return 0;
}
```

*Why my code not passing all test cases.*

Comment: Can you please edit and fix the code formatting.

Comment: Does your code fail for the sample test case? If yes, what does your code result with? If not, can you come up with test cases where your code will fail?

Comment: sorry sir test cases are hidden.

Comment: @yashavKumar: Are you sure the issue is not with how you are reading the array in from the user? The code shown looks fine.

Comment: Actually that's a problem even I don't know